# Developing an Office seating plan in ASP.NET/C# with Visual Stduio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, visio

I want to develop a simple seat plan for my office - showing the location of kitchen/toilets and where each person sits - if you then clicked a person it would bring up their contact details (email and phone extension).  For the drawing of the plan I was hoping to use Visio to represent the rooms/desks.  And then I want to use Visual Studio and SQL Server 2008 to store the details (phone/email etc).  Does anyone know firstly will it be easy to port my seat plan drawn in Visio into Visual Studio 2010 and has anyone came across any useful links for something similar to perhaps give me a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that fixed items like the desk locations be a background image and then you overlay it with custom user controls for the seats.

I guess that you could create the desk layout and the seats, separately, in Visio and them save them as image files.

At its simplist each seat could be represented by a button, with an image from Visio and clicking then pops up the relevent data.

Comment: Thanks Chris - I will try this as an approach to start with

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward to draw simple shapes directly to the screen in .Net using classes in the [Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) namespace. Try [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Drawing_Graphics_in_Visual_Basic) as a simple tutorial to get started.

**Edit - Just noticed the ASP tag on your question so this might not be applicable, I'll leave it up just in case though.

Answer (score 0):

You can build very interactive application in your mentioned case. What chrisBD has suggested is the best method . Use some jquery over it to make it more interactive and fancy.